# Installing mmdblookup module for rsyslog on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog, geolocation

I am currently trying to perform an IP lookup in the MaxMind/GeoIP DB lookup via the mmdblookup module of rsyslog. (https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/mmdblookup.html)

As part of the instructions, they specify that I need to (to use the module) to :

> To compile Rsyslog with mmdblookup you’ll need to
>
> - install libmaxminddb-devel package
> - set –enable-mmdblookup on configure

I have no idea what that means, can somebody explain to me what I am supposed to do to use this module?

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. I don't have an Ubuntu system to provide a definitive answer, so I'll leave a comment here to get you started. The instructions mean that you will need to download the source code for `rsyslog` and the `mmdblookup` module, and then compile it on your system. This document should provide a decent start: [Installing rsyslog from Source](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/installation/install_from_source.html)